# Image loading with Kingfisher

Tags: iphone, imagedownload, kingfisher

I am new to IOS development and trying to load image from url using Kingfisher library. I am using Kingfisher 2.6 with Xcode 7 and swift 2.3.

For that i have created a collection view cell with images. All works fine at first run. Images are shown but as i scroll down my collection view all images are gone. No new images are loaded and i also can't see my previous images.

This is my code

```
url = myUrl
url += product.image!

productImage.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: url),placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"),optionsInfo: [KingfisherOptionsInfoItem.CacheMemoryOnly],progressBlock: nil,completionHandler: nil)
```

Please help me to cache and show image.

Comment: KingfisherOptionsInfoItem.CacheMemoryOnly this stands for memory cache only
It won't cache to local storage

Besides why are you appending your url string?

Comment: @RafattouqirRafsun url is not appended....i have posted just bit of code each time i set url variable

Comment: What is happening in your UICollectionViewDelegate's didEndDisplaying method? Obviously the cell is being loaded and displayed, so what is happening when the collection view removes it?

Comment: when i debug at scroll up time image view is nill....